# MongoDB count by referenced document property

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

*db.foos*

```
{
    bar: ObjectId('123')
}
```

*db.bars*

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('123')
    type: 'wine'
}
```

How can I in the simplest way find the number of foo-documents that refers to a bar-document of type 'wine'? Hopefully one that scales to perform fairly well even if the collections should contain a very large number of documents.

Comment: Well you can only really use `$lookup` which is going to add overhead for the "join". Is there perhaps some more data in your '"real" use case that would could use to do this on a single collection? Or is it even practical to add such data.

Comment: My answer will not be solution, but the simple way in my opinion use MongooseJS ODM . With this library help you will be able make all your operation with mongoDB asap.

Comment: @Levon It's really not a solution because mongoose `.populate()` in fact runs "multiple" queries to simulate the appearance of a "join". That's actually worse than `$lookup`. Ideally, regular query operations "should" require no join at all. Either embed data or otherwise include data that allows sufficient filtering. So if it's just an opinion that does not really add anything, then it should not even be a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this aggregation framework query:

```
db.foos.aggregate([
   {$lookup:
     {
       from: "bars",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "docs"
     }
   },
   {$unwind: "$docs"},
   {$match: {"docs.type":"wine"}},
   {$group: {"_id":"$_id", count: {$sum:1}}}
]
)
```

I tested it on these documents:

```
db.foos.insert({"_id":"123"})
db.foos.insert({"_id":"456"})

db.bars.insert({"_id":"123", type:"wine"})
db.bars.insert({"_id":"456", type:"beer"})
```

and for wine type I get as result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "123", 
    "count" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea if there would be performance issues on large data sets? Just asking from previous experience with heavy SQL joins, hoping to avoid having to rewrite aggregate functions as soon as the data starts growing.

Comment: @henit The only recommendation I know is to create an index on the "foreignField", but in your case is the id so it's indexed by definition. The question here could be how many bars object you could have for each foos document? If this cardinality is quite small, you can change your design embedding bars documents in foos documents and avoid joins